# SharePoint 2010 Master Page changes not reflecting

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, master-page

I had to add google analytics code in a `Sharepoint 2010` website. I have added the script to master page from `Sharepoint designer. But the`script` is not reflecting in the site. Do I have to do anything else other than saving the page. If yes, please explain the procedure and steps as I am new to this environment.

Thanks,
Rahul K

Comment: ensure the master page file is published (and approved) as a major version

Comment: Open the space where you file is kept right click and check in as major version . It will reflect.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below mentioned steps:

- In Browser, Open the SharePoint site >> Go to **Site Actions** >> **Site Settings** >> **Galleries**.
- click on **Master pages and page layouts**.
- Find your master page and click on the arrow beside its to open ECB menu.
- **Check In** the master page.
- Publish this master page with Major Version by clicking on **Publish a major version**.
- Also approve the master page by clicking on **Approve/Reject**.

After that your changes will be reflected in the SharePoint site.